# Phonegap / Cordova - File Download (File plugin) - Windows Phone 8

Tags: file, cordova, plugins, windows-phone-8, download

I am developing an application for a radio station, have a section to download your audio programs. Works perfectly on Android and iOS, but Windows Phone starts downloading (very very slow) and after a time the application breaks showing this error message

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Unknown Module. and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

Also during the short time that is downloading shows this message

> DispatchFileTransferProgress : FileTransfer1024600849

The size of the files you download is between 15 and 20 mb. 
Anyone know what happens? Thanks in advance

Edited for add code
Code:

```
    window.requestFileSystem(
    LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function onRequestFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory(
            'Radio', //Directorory was created when apps starts firs time

            { create: true, exclusive: false },

            function(directoryEntry) {

                directoryEntry.getFile(
                    'dummy.html',

                    { create: true, exclusive: false },

                    function onGetFileSuccess(fileEntry) {
                        var path = fileEntry.toURL().replace('dummy.html', '');
                        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                        fileEntry.remove();

                        var url = record.get('file');
                        var file = record.get('file').split('/');

                        fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
                            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                              console.log('Downloaded: ' + ((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100));
                            }
                        };

                        fileTransfer.download(
                            url,
                            path + file[file.length - 1],

                            function(file) {
                                console.log('Downloaded!');
                            },

                            function(error) {
                                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    function fail(error) {
                        console.log('Get file ' + error.code);
                    }
                );
            },

            function fail(error) {
                console.log('Get directory ' + error.code);
            }
        );
    },
    function fail(error) {
        console.log('Get file system ' + error.code);
    }
);
```

Miguel

Comment: Can we see the code which this exception occurs in?

Comment: I edited to add the code, but this code works in Android and iOS. Also in cordova docs for wp8 not specify any quirks. Thanks! :)